# Uploading an image to Firebase Storage using Firebase Functions in a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to implement a feature which allows users to upload a profile photo to a Firebase storage bucket in a Firebase / React app. If there's a simpler way to approach this, let me know.

There are several tutorials and videos that explain this process, but most are somewhat deprecated. So I've made recommended changes where warranted. When I send my image upload POST request via Postman, it works great! But when I attempt to upload the photo via my app itself, two problems arise:

1. In the browser console, I receive a 400 Bad Request:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://APPNAME.cloudfunctions.net/uploadFile/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

2. In logs of the uploadFile firebase function, I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0...
```

I know this latter issue has to do something with JSON parsing, and since I'm not explicitly calling parse() anywhere, I am assuming it happens inside of busboy.

I've tried setting

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

both just inside the function, as well as just inside the cors block (shown below). I also experimented with adding that header as the last argument to the axios request itself.

From within the uploadFile firebase function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const fs = require('fs');

const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'the-project-name',
  keyFilename: 'the-project-name-firebase-adminsdk-rplsy-85bdb1984f.json'
});

exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Only POST requests are supported for profile photo upload.'
      });
    }
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    let uploadData = null;

    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename)
      uploadData = { file: filepath, type: mimetype }
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', () => {
      const bucket = storage.bucket('the-project-name.appspot.com')
      bucket.upload(uploadData.file, {
        uploadType: 'media',
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: uploadData.type
          }
        }
      })
        .then(() => {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'It worked!'
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return res.status(500).json({
            error: err
          });
        })
    });
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
      });
    });
```

The upload handler within the form component:

```
fileUploadHandler() {
  const { selectedFile } = this.state;
  console.log({ selectedFile });

if (selectedFile) {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://us-central1-the-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/uploadFile/',
  data: selectedFile,
  headers

})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("I think it worked...");
    console.log(response)
})
.catch((err) => {
   console.log("axios.post() did not succeed.")
});
  } else {
    console.log("No file stored in local component state.")
  }
}
```

Expected result: The image is uploaded into firebase storage.

Actual result:

(1) The image can be uploaded to the firebase storage bucket from Postman (using the existing firebase REST route), but cannot be uploaded using the react app. CORS error in browser console states that the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present, even though I've put it in three places in an attempt to resolve the error.

(2) Firebase function's log returns a JSON.parse() error.

Comment: Have you checked if the cloud function is invoked with the "OPTIONS" verb? Browsers usually do an OPTIONS request before the actual one, to check the presence of the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, which should be in server-side only. 
That said, why upload a binary through a cloud function when you can upload to cloud storage directly from your webapp and send to the server only the path in a plain json request?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try Cloud Storage for Firebase?

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files